# Complex integral of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to find the integral along $\partial D$ of 
$$
\mathrm{f}(z) =
{z^4 + 1 \over z^2(z - 3)(3z - 1)}
\quad\text{where } D \text{ is the open unit disc centred at } z=0.
$$

It's clear that I have to use the Cauchy's theorem, but when the pole is $z=0$ is where I have problems.

Comment: Maybe residue theorem?

Comment: Might you have meant $\partial D$ is the _boundary_ of the unit disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the $z^2$ in the denominator, $g(z)=z^2f(z)=1/3+(10/9)z+(91/27)z^2+\cdots.$ So after division by $z^2,$ the residue at $z=0$ of $f$ is $10/9.$ The residue theorem can now be applied.

Comment: I was thinking in using separation through partial fractions, but it's way too long.

Comment: For partial fractions only need (after factoring out a constant) to get a partial fraction for a term of the form $1/((x+a)(x+b)).$ This can be done using the difference $1/(x+a)-1/(x+b)=(b-a)/[(x-a)(x-b)].$ So one would need to divide this by $b-a$ etc.

Comment: As @Stahl notes, there is another pole at $z=1/3$ whose residue needs to be computed, since $1/3$ is inside the unit disc.

Answer (score 1):

By the residue theorem,
$$
\int_\gamma\!\frac{z^4 + 1}{z^2(z - 3)(3z - 1)}\,dz = 2\pi i\left(\operatorname{Res}(f,0) + \operatorname{Res}(f,1/3)\right).
$$
Now, because $z = 1/3$ is a simple pole of $f$, 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Res}(f,1/3) &= \lim_{z\to 1/3}(z - 1/3)f(z)\\
&=\lim_{z\to 1/3}\frac{z^4 + 1}{3z^2(z - 3)}\\
&=\frac{(1/3)^4 + 1}{3(1/3)^2((1/3) - 3)}\\
&=-\frac{41}{36}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, $z = 0$ is a pole of order $2$ of $f$, so
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Res}(f,0) &= \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left[z^2f(z)\right]\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac{z^4 + 1}{(z - 3)(3z - 1)}\right]\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{2 (5 - 3 z + 6 z^3 - 15 z^4 + 3 z^5)}{(-3 + z)^2 (-1 + 3 z)^2}\\
&= \frac{10}{9}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
\int_\gamma\!\frac{z^4 + 1}{z^2(z - 3)(3z - 1)}\,dz = 2\pi i\left(-\frac{41}{36} + \frac{10}{9}\right) = \frac{-\pi i}{18}.
$$

Comment: All of this in $δD$, Right?

Comment: The integral is over the boundary $\partial D$ of the open unit disc (I've called it $\gamma$), if that's what you're asking. The points $z = 0$ and $z = 1/3$ are the only points in the interior of $D$ where $f$ is not holomorphic, which is why you need to compute the residue at both of them if you want to apply the residue theorem.

Comment: Oh! Got it. Thank you.